# Difficulty understanding how to declare a parent class's function in an extended class?

Tags: php, oop

```
class Bar{        
    public function test(){
        $this->testPublic();
        $this->testPrivate();
    }

    public function testPublic(){
        echo "Bar::testPublic\n";
    }

    private function testPrivate(){
        echo "Bar::testPrivate\n";
    }        
}

class Foo extends Bar{
    public function testPublic(){
        echo "Foo::testPublic\n";
    }
    private function testPrivate(){
        echo "Foo::testPrivate\n";
    }

}

$myFoo = new Foo();
$myFoo->test();
//Foo::testPublic
//Bar::testPrivate
```

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding this output.  Would someone be able to give me a clear succinct explanation of what is going on?  I'm learning OOP and wanted to know how to use extensions to override the parent class functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `test()` method calls 2 methods:

1. `testPublic` - it's a public one, so it was overriden in the `Foo`. So the `Foo::testPublic` is called
2. `testPrivate` - it's a private one, so it's only visible for each class itself. For the caller method (it's `Bar`) - it's a `Bar::testPrivate`

So - if the method is `public` or `protected` - it can be overriden and called from the ancestor/child; if it's `private` - it cannot.

Answer (score 0):

The *$this* references the current object. So when you do the following.

> $this->testPublic();

It will call testPublic() for the **top** most class that implements that function.

If you want to only call the parent class, then there is the parent keyword.

> parent::testPublic();

That will call testPublic() on the class **below** the current object.

Becare full not to confuse the -> operator with the :: operator.

The :: operator references the *class* definition of an object, where as -> references the instance of an object.

```
 self::testPublic();
 $foo::testPublic();
```

That references a static function called testPublic(), and static methods are defined at the class level.

```
 $foo->testPublic();
 $this->testPublic();
```

That references a function as part of the instance of an object, and there is a vtable used to look up which object instance level should be called.